# Can't add user using php form in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my first question here. I hope I will find the answer.
As the title says I am unable to add users using form I created in html and I am unable to add a user using php function into database.

**db.php**

```
<?php
$db['db_host'] = 'localhost';
$db['db_user'] = 'root';
$db['db_pass'] = '';
$db['db_name'] = 'cms';
foreach($db as $key => $value){
define(strtoupper($key),$value);
}

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
//you need to exit the script, if there is an error
exit();
}

?>
add-user.php
    <?php
    require_once('inc/top.php'); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('Location:login.php');
    }

    else if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and $_SESSION['role'] =='author'){
    header('Location:index.php');
    }
    ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
                    <?php require_once('inc/header.php');?>
        <div class="container-fluid body-section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <?php require_once('inc/sidebar.php');?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h1><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add User<small>Add 
                New User</small></h1>
                           <hr>
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer">
      </i> Dashboard</a></li>
                          <li class="active"><i class="fa fa-user-plus">
     </i>Add New User</li>
                          </ol>

                          <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        $date=time();
                        $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first-name']);
                        $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['last-name']);
                        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,strtolower($_POST['username']));
                        $username_trim=preg_replace('/\s*/','',$username);
                        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,strtolower($_POST['email']));
                        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
                        $role = $_POST['role'];
                        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                        $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

                        $check_query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' or email='$email'";
                        $check_run=mysqli_query($con,$check_query);
                        $salt_query="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
                        $salt_run=mysqli_query($con,$salt_query);
                        $salt_row=mysqli_fetch_array($salt_run);
                        $salt=$salt_row['salt'];
                        $password=crypt($password, $salt);

                        if(empty($first_name) or empty($last_name) or empty($username) or empty($email) or empty($password) or empty($image)) {
                            $error="All field Required";

                        }
                        else if($username!=$username_trim){
                            $error="Don't use spaces in username";

                        }
                        else if(mysqli_num_rows($check_run)){
                            $error="Username or Email Already Exist";
                        }
                        else{

                            $insert_query="INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`, `image`, `password`, `role`) VALUES (NULL, NULL', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$email', '$image', '$password', '$role')";
                            if(mysqli_query($con,$insert_query)){
                                $msg="User has been Added";
                                move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"img/$image");

                            }
                            else{
                                $error="user has not been Added";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="first-name">First Name:*</label>
                                  <?php
                                  if(isset($error)){
                                      echo "<span class='pull-right' style='color:red;'>$error</span>";
                                  }
                                  else if(isset($msg)){
                                      echo "<span class='pull-right' style='color:green;'>$msg</span>";
                                  }

                                  ?>
                                  <input type="text" name="first-name"  value="<?php if(isset($first_name)){ echo $first_name;}?>" id="first-name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="last-name">Last Name:*</label>
                                  <input type="text" name="last-name" value="<?php if(isset($last_name)){ echo $last_name;}?>" id="last-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="username">Username:*</label>
                                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if(isset($username)){ echo $username;}?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="email">Email:*</label>
                                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  value="<?php if(isset($email)){ echo $email;}?>"  class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="Password">Password:*</label>
                                  <input type="password" name="password"  id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="role">Role:*</label>
                                  <select name="role" id="role" class="form-control">
                                  <option value="author">Author</option>
                                  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                  </select>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="image">Profile Picture:*</label>
                                  <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
                              </div>



                              <input type="submit" value="Add User" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

                          </form>


                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                          <?php
                          if(isset($check_image)){

                              echo "<img src='img/$check_image' width='100%'>";
                          }

                          ?>

                      </div>
                  </div>    

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
           <?php require_once('inc/footer.php');?>
```

I have done many searches but didn't find it to work the code and add user. whenever I try to add a user as "author" or "admin" it says "user has not been added". 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide the error you are getting ?

Comment: the error is "user has not been added"

Comment: try to add the mysqli error to your string to see what's wrong. ```$error = "user has not beed Added ". mysqli_error($con);```

Comment: it says this error.
"user has not beed Added You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near "

Comment: You seem to have an extra apostrophe: `NULL'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this query where you insert:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`date`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`, `image`, `password`, `role`) VALUES (NULL, '$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$email', '$image', '$password', '$role');
```

Comment: got this error after adding INSERT INTO 
"user has not beed Added Column 'id' cannot be null"

Comment: allright, you had an syntax error and now you are getting different error. Let me update and it will work

Comment: If you defined the id column "auto_increment", then you should not set id in your insert query.

Comment: yeah sure i am waiting

Comment: Thanks a lot i have fixed it the id and date should not been added and i have removed it and it worked great...
added this code
       " $insert_query="INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `email`, `image`, `password`, `role`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$username', '$email', '$image', '$password', '$role')";"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing id and date because it is auto_increment and it should not have been used into insert into function